# How to write conditional statements in Gams

Tags: modeling, gams-math

I'm new in the Gams and I try to solve a problem for my term project. Although the code does not give errors, I am not sure of its correctness.

`kisit5(i,h,k)$( (ord(i)>=2) and (ord(h)<ord(i)) and (ord(h) < ord(k)) )`

In the conditional part, I wanted to write that expression: ∀i=2,...,n and h<i,k.

Is it correct or should I write it in a different form?

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct. You can just write some dummy code to verify it yourself:

```
Set i /1*4/
    h /1*4/
    k /1*4/
    kisit5(i,h,k);

kisit5(i,h,k)$( (ord(i)>=2) and (ord(h)<ord(i)) and (ord(h) < ord(k)) ) = yes;

display kisit5;
```

The result will be printed to the lst file. Or you run it with GDX creation (`F10` in GAMS Studio), and look at it in the GDX Viewer of GAMS Studio.